# GLEventListener JOGL implemented functions are not being called

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

I"m using Eclipse, Java, and JOGL4. I'm trying to draw a simple triangle on a swing canvas. However, the GLEventListener functions aren't being called.

I have two Java classes, a UI class that sets up the UI using Swing and extends GLEventListener. So I have the init, display, dispose, functions in my class. 
I also have a second class that the first class is supposed to call. However, the UI class's functions - init and display - don't seem to ever be called.

So, for example, the UI class have a function init() that calls the second classes init() function. For example:

```
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Display");
            renderer.display(arg0);

        }

        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Dispose");
        }
        @Override
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Init");
            renderer.init(arg0);
        }
        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Reshape");
        }
```

The output text, "init", "display", "dispose", and "Reshape" never show up. Nothing is ever drawn, even though display is called in the renderer class. The class is too big to paste here, but this is the header of the class and the end of it with the listeners functions.

```
    package IDE;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

import com.jogamp.newt.Display;
import com.jogamp.newt.NewtFactory;
import com.jogamp.newt.Screen;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowUpdateEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableFactory;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

import Central.GLRenderer;
import Listeners.BasicMenuListener;

public class UserInterface implements GLEventListener, KeyListener{
    private JTree tree;
    JPopupMenu popupmenu;
    GLRenderer renderer = new GLRenderer();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("NecroTEK 3D Game Graphics Engine");

...

                public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Display");
                renderer.display(arg0);

            }

            public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Dispose");
            }
            @Override
            public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Init");
                renderer.init(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Reshape");
            }


            /**************/
            // An inner class to check whether mouse events are the popup trigger
            class MousePopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    checkPopup(e);
                }

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    checkPopup(e);
                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    checkPopup(e);
                }

                private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        popupmenu.show(popupmenu, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }
            }


            // An inner class to show when popup events occur
            class PopupPrintListener implements PopupMenuListener {
                public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Popup menu will be visible!");
                }

                public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Popup menu will be invisible!");
                }

                public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Popup menu is hidden!");
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }






}
```

Ok, it is calling Display now, but it still isn't drawing. This is my render function that is called by display:

```
public void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl2.glClear( GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    // draw a triangle filling the window
    gl2.glLoadIdentity();
    gl2.glBegin( GL2.GL_TRIANGLES );
    gl2.glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );
    gl2.glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
    gl2.glColor3f( 0, 1, 0 );
    gl2.glVertex2f( width, 0 );
    gl2.glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 );
    gl2.glVertex2f( width / 2, height );
    gl2.glEnd();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ted, probably you are just missing the `animator`

Comment: What is the animator for? And its required?

Comment: The animator basically takes care of calling continuously the `display()` based on its configuration. Please show us the part of code where you init opengl (profiles and capabilities)

Comment: Bravo, does it work now?

Comment: elect is right, you can look at my rudimentary example: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98 I advise you to look at our wiki before asking questions about JOGL here: http://jogamp.org/wiki/

Comment: If the FPSAnimator doesn't work, rather use a plain Animator and enable v-sync.